# TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a function in my angular project, and i need to mock formData.append, but a don't know how, i have this error:

TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

My typescript code:

```
sendFile(file: File) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileKey', file, file.name);

        return new Promise((resolve, error) => {
            this.http.post<any>(`/fileupload`, formData)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    if (res.success) {
                        resolve(res.data);
                    } else {
                        console.error(res);
                        if (res.code == 401) {
                            this.cookie.removeAll();
                            location.href = "/login";
                        }
                        error(res);
                    }
                })
        })
    }
```

and this is my test:

```
describe('sendFile()', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    });

    it('Should http to send the request', () => {
      const file: File = {
        size: 0,
        name: 'test.txt',
        type: 'text/plain',
      } as any;

      service.sendFile(file).then(res => expect(res).toBeTruthy());

      const request = httpMock.expectOne('/fileupload');

      expect(request.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    });
```